# F# XUnit test deadlocks when initializer has dependency

Tags: f#, xunit

I am having problems with a test in a netcoreapp2.2 .net core test project.

Before the tests starts I need to fetch some data that will be shared between the tests.

However, when running the following test from command line it will hang.
Executing the test like this:

`dotnet test --filter "Test async initialization"`

The faulty code looks like this:

```
let c = new HttpClient (BaseAddress = (Uri "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"))    

let luke = 
    async {                
        return! c.GetStringAsync "" |> Async.AwaitTask        
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously

[<Fact>]
let ``Test async initialization`` () =  
    Assert.NotNull(luke)
```

While if I put the creation of the HttpClient inside the luke fetcher like this it works:

```
let luke = 
    let c = new HttpClient (BaseAddress = (Uri "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"))
    async {                
        return! c.GetStringAsync "" |> Async.AwaitTask        
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously

[<Fact>]
let ``Test async initialization`` () =  
    Assert.NotNull(luke)
```

This means I can't share the same HttpClient between different fetchers.

Anyone knows what is going on, and how to share the same client between multiple functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because the "initialization" code isn't really initialization code. Those are just two static fields that will be evaluated only when requested. If you debug the unit test you'll see that `c` and `luke` execute only when execution reaches the line

```
Assert.NotNull(luke)
```

If you use a decompiler like JustDecompile you'll see that the module's code is placed in a static class called `Tests$` whose static constructor initializes its own `c` and `luke` properties. `Test async initialization` is placed in a `Tests` class with its own `c` and `luke` properties  that delegate to the `Tests$` class.

Long story sort, none of that "initialization" code runs until the value of `luke` is requested. I don't know why that ends up blocking the test, most likely there's a conflict with the test runner. It's enough that the initialization code doesn't run at initialization.

To make the initialization code run when it should, a "classic" test type can be used :

```
namespace MyTests


open System
open Xunit
open System.Net.Http
open Xunit.Abstractions

type Tests() =

    static let c = new HttpClient (BaseAddress = (Uri "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"))    

    static let luke = 
        async {                
            return! c.GetStringAsync "" |> Async.AwaitTask        
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously

    static do 
        //Pity we can't actually print here
        printfn "Even more initialization!"

    [<Fact>]
    let ``Test async initialization`` () =  
        Assert.NotNull(luke)
```

The static bindings in this case are executed before any of the tests, as they should, and the code doesn't block. This initialization will happen only once.

To [capture output](http://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output) the test class constructor should accept an ITestOutputHelper parameter. That's easy to do now that we have a test class :

```
type Tests(output:ITestOutputHelper) =

    ...

    [<Fact>]
    let ``Test async initialization`` () =  
        Assert.NotNull(luke)
        output.WriteLine "It worked!"
```

Per-test initialization should go in a `do` block :

```
type Tests(output:ITestOutputHelper) =

    do
      output.WriteLine "This prints before each test"
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution with a type seems to work fine.
However someone else posted an answer and then deleted it with another solution that also seems to work fine. 
Simply removing the async from the ´luke´ initializer and then wrap the actual test in an async instead also seems to work. Like this:

let luke = c.GetStringAsync "" |> Async.AwaitTask 

[<Fact>]
let ``Test async initialization`` () =
   async{ 
      let! l = luke
      Assert.NotNull(l)
   }
But I guess the outhelper is a good reason to use a type

Comment: @OlavNybø removing `async` doesn't fix the main problem - the initialization code *doesn't* run when it's expected to run. Its behaviour may not be what you expect it to be either - with a module, you can only have fixture setup code, ie code that runs before all other tests and initializes *shared* state. You can't have test setup code, ie code that runs before each test to clean up and initialize state that's only visible to each individual test.